# New EEE-PC 901 replacement screen has display is not working properly

Tags: display, hardware-failure, laptop-display, eee-pc

I recently bought a replacement screen for Asus EEE 901 Laptop as old screen had a crack. Now the problem is the replacement screen doesn't work. I switch back to broken screen and it was fine. Finally when I admired closely the screen displayed the content but visibility was very hard in back screen. It felt like screen had no power supply or no brightness. How do fix the problem?

Update: I got reply from seller and the person said:

> Sorry to hear that the screen does not work, it was working in my EeePC 901 (Windows XP).
>
> I have googled the problem and it may be a BIOS compatibility issue. However I wonder if you have tried the brightness keys or this link: http://www.ehow.com/how_5981580_fix-eee-pc-black-screen.html

Comment: Sounds like the replacement screen is not working and you need a different one. Can you return it?

Comment: I asked the seller and he suggested bios problem. I checked the connection with broken screen and bios seemed to be fine. Is there any possible way to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a bad display to me. If you could, send it back and get a replacement. Save your self the hassle of trying to fix it your self..